# Maya: Having trouble writing a script to cut a mesh into equal pieces

Tags: scripting, maya, mel, pymel

I want to split a mesh into sections based on a number of vertices.  Essentially, I want a mesh cut into sections of 300 verts each with a remainder section of whatever is left over.

I've done this for the most part (i can get verts/faces, etc) but I'm having trouble figuring a graceful way of iterating through the extracted meshes.

I'm using polyChipOff which has no return value for the faces it chipped, so it's entirely new objects that are created that i have no handle to so i can't just continue chipping away from the previous piece as it no longer exists.

Any advice on how to go about this better?

I've thought of either iterating through all meshes in the scene for new ones (cache them at the start) or using a scriptJob to detect new objects being made.  Both of those seem very hacky so was curious if anyone had advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this method:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

shape = cmds.listRelatives(p=True)
object = cmds.listRelatives(a, p=True)
selectedFace = cmds.ls(sl=True)

cmds.select(object[0] + '.f[:]', tgl=True)
unselecetedFace = cmds.ls(sl=True)

duplicated = cmds.duplicate(object, un=True)[0]
cmds.delete(duplicated, ch=True)
cmds.delete(selectedFace)

for i in range(len(unselecetedFace)):
    unselecetedFace[i] = unselecetedFace[i].replace(object[0],duplicated)

cmds.delete(unselecetedFace)
cmds.select(duplicated)
```

Comment: Ahh very interesting, i didn't think about duplicates sharing the same vert order.  This seems like it may be a bit slower than I would like but you never know.  I will try it out and compare!